# Reliable Services seem to deactivate

Tags: azure-service-fabric

I'm running into slowness in my stateful services that haven't had activity in awhile.  It seems that the first call after some period of inactivity is incredibly slow (10+seconds).  Subsequent calls do not suffer this problem.  This seems to be a classic case of a service deactivating and waking up.

I'm aware that stateful actors do this, however, this is occurring for stateful services.  This is being noticed in my dev and test clusters, where activity is sparse and inconsistent.  For disclosure, these environments are running on the lowest resources possible (A0 vms, bronze tier availability).  Regardless, I thought stateful services were supposed to remain always running.

How would I keep them warm and activated?  Additionally, how would I diagnose what is actually happening?

Answer (score 0):

Service Fabric doesn't do anything in terms of deactivating or putting services to sleep. Let's look at what a running named instance of a Reliable Service written in C# on Windows really *is*:

- A .NET object instance running inside a process.

That's all. Service Fabric won't shut down the process if it's "idle" (whatever that means - Service Fabric has no such definition), and the object instance is strongly rooted so it won't be garbage collected.

So really all the same factors that would apply to any .NET application apply here.

If I had to take a guess - without knowing anything else about your application - the A0 VMs are most likely to blame. You have less than 1 GB of memory, so paging might be an issue. You have a fraction of a shared CPU core, so that might be an issue.

I never recommend using A0s. Not only because the extremely limited power can affect your services, but it can also affect the Service Fabric system services that keep your services alive and healthy.

Comment: I'll try bumping them up to A1's, which is too bad since dev and test barely need anything.  Even with 1GB of memory, these services in the current state are just holding a reliable dictionary each, with about 5 records in it.  It is odd that they seem to all exhibit this behavior.  Could it be something to do with the ASP.NET Core Web Api?  It's running in the same cluster, acting as the application facade between the client and the services.

Comment: That's possible. Which web host are you using with ASP.NET Core? Kestrel or WebListener?

Comment: ASP.NET Core with Kestrel middleware.